# Database with millions of tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I often read about MySQL databases which are inperformant when a certain amout of tables exists in a database.
My problem is that all the users of my system are able to create an exercise and each of those exercises is stored as an extra table. Theoretically it would be possible that after 5 years more than 100,000 or even 2,000,000 tables exist.
Is this a problem for the MySQL system and what would be a better way to handle this?

Comment: COnsidered fixing that totally broken design?

Comment: @TomTom I was thinking about the design - but I am new to databases and don't really know where I should learn about db designs - can you suggest a website or a good article that introduces me to the different design possibilities?

Comment: Books? I mean, seirously, I learned SQL in a book like 30 years ago. I am sure in the meantime more books have been written. Oh, and as basic: Every design with fully dynamic tables generally is broken. There are some exceptions, but those are FEW.

Comment: Okay thanks for that  advise! Then I am just gonna google for some tutorials about that topic.

Comment: So, you think that "some tutorials" is as good as reading a 200 page book that was writte nby somoene actualyl taking the time? Seriously? Yeah. Have fun. Do not wonder when you fail in every quizz because lack of real knowledge.

Comment: @TomTom Do not worry, I am not a script kiddie. I attend an IT school anyway and we are gonna have a subject for databases next year but I don't want to wait that long - so what I don't learn now I will learn there but also I can tell you that with "some tutorials" I did not mean 2 YT videos but a written tutorial that is of course of the same length like a book but for free - and I am sure there is one...

Comment: @TomTomWhat do you think about this: http://www.darkopetrovic.com/pdf/Data-Modeling-and-Relational-Database-Design.pdf

Comment: TOC looks good. Otherwise look for books by Joe Celko once you are more advanced And for example - the Data Model Ressource Book series are always good ;)

Comment: What is the advantage to putting all of this in one database?  Maybe a different database for each user would work out better.

Comment: @WalterMitty I already got a better design now that works with just 1 table but a lot of rows...
But anyways - why the hell would I create 10000 databases when I have 10000 users? You can't tell me that this is more performant...?

Comment: I haven't investigated such a design myself, and I'm not claiming that it would be performant.  But your million table solution was clearly bad.  I'm glad you now have a better choice.

Comment: @TheProgrammer - One table with a billion rows will be more performant that a million tables with a thousand rows each.  Locating the table and opening it are a big issue when there are lots of table.

Comment: @TheProgrammer - (comments on darkop...):  * Not a single line of SQL.  * The very basic concept `JOIN` is mentioned 48 times, but seeming without a definition.  * `LEFT JOIN`, semi-join, etc, don't seem to be mentioned.

Comment: It might be better to have thousands of databases (easy to drop), each with a handful of tables that are actively used for a brief time.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL itself [does not have a built-in limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/database-count-limit.html) on the number of databases or tables. However, each database will open a new directory and each table may result in up to three files in that directory. If your system cannot handle that efficiently, you may face problems after some time.

I would suggest that you keep a record of the tables with timestamps when they are created by your users. Then you can drop them safely once they are obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `trigger` on every table use. Create a `active_tables` table and make an entry every time on each new table creation with the date&time. And also create a `trigger` for `select, update, delete OR schema modification` OR `any DML` action and update your table modification time in the `active_table` then each day runs a `CRON` job to delete all the table which are old and not used in last 6 months.